# Is it acceptable to query a mongoose database with undefined variable?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As you can see from the code, I'm returning all users by querying with an undefined variable if param isn't defined. Is this acceptable to do this, or is there some drawback I'm not seeing?

```
get: function(param, callback){
    var query;
    if (param) {
        query = {username: param}
    }
    User.find(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
            return;
        }
        callback(null, result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hmm. For sanity sake I would at least make that `var query = {}` and if you really only want results for one `"username"` then I would simply return where no parameter was supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from [the source](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/dc6f8872740256a878ecc6bbcdbb1eb5dd83d1a6/lib/model.js#L1203) mongoose takes care of this for you:

```
Model.find = function find(conditions, projection, options, callback) {
  if (typeof conditions === 'function') {
    callback = conditions;
    conditions = {};
```

So, you *can* pass undefinded as `conditions`

As suggested in the comments, however, I would change to:

```
var query = {}
```

So you are always passing in an empty object.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.